# Opening new windows the same place(x.y) as the first window opened [Win8.1]

Tags: windows

I've recently re-installed my windows 8.1 for some reasons and came across with some small, but very annoying problem to me.

You see, when I open say My Computer folder, and resize it as I like and then close it, it will appear the same place(x, y) I opened it last time. But, if I'll try to open another folder window, say My Documents, but without closing the My Computer one, the My Document folder will NOT be the same place as My Computer is, instead it appears just a little bit lower-right from the My Computer.

It wasn't like this before and It's really annoying for me. How can I resolve this, so the new folder windows will appear just the same place as the last one, without closing the first folder-window.

Hope someone will know the answer. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open any folder Then In the Top bar Goto View in that you will find options open folder options and untick the option Launch folder windows in separate process.

[image]

Comment: fixer i was not allowed to post image at my reputation so i posted the link to the same

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help in my case. I'm using Win 8.1 64bit with last updates. Perhaps, there's something else to do with it?